# Django : Migration of polymorphic models back to a single base class

Tags: python, django, database-migration

Let's suppose [I have a polymorphic model](https://github.com/Pierre-Sassoulas/django-survey/blob/djangopolymorphic/survey/models/answer.py) and I want to get rid of it.

```
class AnswerBase(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="answers")
    response = models.ForeignKey(Response, related_name="answers")


class AnswerText(AnswerBase):
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class AnswerInteger(AnswerBase):
    body = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When I want to get all the answers I can never access "body" or I need to try to get the instance of a sub-class by trial and error.

```
# Query set of answerBase, no access to body   
AnswerBase.objects.all()
question = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
# Query set of answerBase, no access to body (even with django-polymorphic)
question.answers.all()
```

I don't want to use django-polymorphic because of performances, because it does not seem to work for foreignKey relation, and because I don't want my model to be too complicated. So I want this polymorphic architecture to become [this simplified one](https://github.com/Pierre-Sassoulas/django-survey/blob/master/survey/models/answer.py) :

```
class Answer(models.Model):

    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="answers")
    response = models.ForeignKey(Response, related_name="answers")
    body = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The migrations cannot be created automatically, it would delete all older answers in the database. I've read the [Schema Editor documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/schema-editor/) but it does not seem there is a buildin to migrate a model to something that already exists. So I want to create my own operation to save the `AnswerText` and `AnswerInteger` as an `Answer` then delete `AnswerText` and `AnswerInteger`. I'm hoping I won't have to write SQL directly, but maybe that's the only solution ? My migration file looks like this. I created an Operation called MigrateAnswer :

```
from myapp.migrations import MigrateAnswer


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel("AnswerBase", "Answer"),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='answer',
            name='body',
            field=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),
        MigrateAnswer("AnswerInteger"),
        MigrateAnswer("AnswerText"),
        migrations.DeleteModel(name='AnswerInteger',),
        migrations.DeleteModel(name='AnswerText',),
    ]
```

So what I want to do in MigrateAnswer is to migrate the value for an old model (`AnswerInteger` and `AnswerText`) to the base class (now named `Answer`, previousely `AnswerBase`). Here's my operation class :

```
from django.db.migrations.operations.base import Operation


class MigrateAnswer(Operation):

    reversible = False

    def __init__(self, model_name):
        self.old_name = model_name

    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state,
                          to_state):
        new_model = to_state.apps.get_model(app_label, "Answer")
        old_model = from_state.apps.get_model(app_label, self.old_name)
        for field in old_model._meta.local_fields:
            # loop on "question", "reponse" and "body"
            # schema_editor.alter_field() Alter a field on a single model
            # schema_editor.add_field() + remove_field() Does not permit 
            # to migrate the value from the old field to the new one
            pass
```

So my question is : Is it possible to do this wihout using "execute" (ie : without writing SQL). If so what should I do in the for loop of my Operation ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to write an Operations class; data migrations can be done simply with a RunPython call, as [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) show.

Within that function you can use perfectly normal model instance methods; since you know the fields you want to move the data for, there is no need to get them via meta lookups.

However you will need to temporarily call the new body field a different name, so it doesn't conflict with the old fields on the subclasses; you can rename it back at the end and delete the child classes because the value will be in the base class.

```
def migrate_answers(apps, schema_editor):
    classes = []
    classes_str = ['AnswerText', 'AnswerInteger']
    for class_name in classes_str:
        classes.append(apps.get_model('survey', class_name))
    for class_ in classes:
        for answer in class_.objects.all():
            answer.new_body = answer.body
            answer.save()

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='answerbase',
        name='new_body',
        field=models.TextField(blank=True, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.RunPython(migrate_answers),
    migrations.DeleteModel(name='AnswerInteger',),
    migrations.DeleteModel(name='AnswerText',),
    migrations.RenameField('AnswerBase', 'new_body', 'body'),
    migrations.RenameModel("AnswerBase", "Answer"),
]
```

Comment: Thank you it has been really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an empty migration for the app you want to do these modifications and use the [migrations.RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) Class to execute custom python functions.

1. Inside these functions you can have access to your models
2. The Django ORM that you can do data manipulation.
3. Pure python, no raw SQL.